# how to make my dropdown menu work correctly (dropdown link doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the link dropdown to refer on another page how can i do that.
Found nothing on the internet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

is it possible this way or should i use another method to create that type of dropdownmenu? I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Are you asking for a drop down link to open a new tab/page when clicked?

Comment: No the Link with Label: Dropdown should directly lead me on the index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, just put the URL you want to go to inside the `href` attribute. Then use the `target="_blank"` attribute setting to tell the browser you want the link to open in a new blank tab.

**Update**
Based on comments, if you want the top level menu item "Dropdown" also linked, then simply replace the `"javascript:void(0)"` with the link you want. The reason for that javascript is to prevent the browser from taking action and trying to open a link when there is none. So just replace it with an actual link and you are good.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
      <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
      <a href="http://www.amazon.com" target="_blank">Amazon</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the line <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a> to lead me somewhere

Comment: What do you mean by "line"?

Comment: aah ok i thought the javascript:void(0) had any function to the dropdownmenu

Comment: No, that's just preventing the default browser action of trying to open a link when there is none.

Answer (score 0):

"Found nothing on the internet" is a pretty surprising claim to make.

Nevertheless, you can simply change the `href` value to point to the website you would like, for example `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">...</a>` will take you to the home page of this site.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
      <a href="https://example.com">Example</a>
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```